# Conda is corrupted after pip install conda

Tags: python, pip, conda

My conda is corrupted after I run command "pip install conda". Is there any way to recover it ? Thanks

Here's the error I see when running conda command

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply, follow the instructions given in the error:
Download miniconda, then run the script file by typing following command: `bash <file_name.sh>` e.g.
`bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`.

Now reopen the terminal for the changes to take effect.

If conda is already installed on your system, you can reinstall it with the `-f` force option, for example,
`bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -f`

To test your installation, enter the command `conda --version`. If installed correctly, you will see the version of conda installed.

miniconda: https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

conda troubleshooting: https://conda.io/docs/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: It's good to notice that Mac users sometimes forget to use sudo. This can cause the same issue described as it has happened to me.

Comment: I think that a good idea will be to first uninstall conda from pip. At least it worked for me. `pip uninstall conda`

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing this problem in Virtual Machine (VM) then you have to activate the main environment by running below line of code:

```
source /anaconda_installation_folder_path/bin/activate
```

Once you are in your main environment you can work with conda.

Comment: really cool answer!  perfectly resolve my problem!  my problem:  i can not use conda from comm user  but ok with root user

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: nothing is corrupted, the message you're seeing is a hardcoded stub and could be fixed.

*conda* package manager actually **can** be used with regular python installation.

**Update**: I've been tinkering with the described method and found that you should use `conda install --dry-run ...` to see changes that are going to happen. Some conda packages depend on other python version, which would overwrite the installed one. There's might be a solution for this with changing conda channels or using virtualenv. I also found that `--dry-run` doesn't work when using local package archives.

I'll show you how to run cudatoolkit 9.1 without any Anaconda and python-3.6-amd64. I'm using cuda 9.1 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64).

Since conda is artificially tethered with Anaconda, you have to untie them.
I recommend you to backup up python installation directory you'll be working with (or use virtualenv).

1. Install *menuinst* dependency.
   At the moment, it's broken from PyPi, so get if from 
   [github](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/releases/tag/1.4.8). Build it and install `python setup.py install`

This package is problematic also in Anaconda distribution. It triggers series of  requests for admin rights every time, which should be suppressed with `conda ... --no-shortcuts` option.

2. `pip install pypiwin32`, dependency of (1)
3. `pip install conda`, requires (1)
4. Move to python installation directory. **./Scripts/conda.exe** should exist.
5. Move to **./Lib/site-packages/conda**

Search directory recursively for **pip_warning** substring in following **TEXT** file types: .py, .json, .txt

6. Replace matching substrings **pip_warning** with **main**

Don't forget to abide the syntax of file types you'd be editing.

7. Now open the **./Scripts/conda.exe** executable in any hex-editor and 
   find **pip_warning**, carefully overwrite it with **main** and wipe the
   rest with spaces until bytes **import main**

Check for file size not have changed.

8. Remove any **__pycache__** dirs if found in **./Lib/site-packages/conda**

**If you only need working conda without cuda, you're done here.**

9. Run `conda install mkl`, `pip install llvmlite numpy`
10. Download packages [cudatoolkit-9.1-0.tar.bz2](https://anaconda.org/numba/cudatoolkit/files) 
    and [numba-0.36.2.tar.bz2](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numba/files?version=0.36.2)
    and run

`conda install cudatoolkit-9.1-0.tar.bz2`

`conda install numba-0.36.2-***.tar.bz2`

Wait a little while unpacking finished.

Now try [these](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/intrinsics.html#example) examples, they should work and your gpu monitor show some activity. `conda ...` commands also do work.

With Linux, I guess instructions are the same, just would be .sh or ELF in place of .exe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what worked was:

```
pip uninstall conda
```

and then installing [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

Answer (score 0):

Download miniconda, then run the script file by typing following command: bash <file_name.sh> e.g. bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -u

'-u' : update tag, used if the original conda bash paths get lost due to certain modifications in the .bashrc file