# (on Windows) Conda is corrupted after pip install conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have already seen the answers from [Conda is corrupted after pip install conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548991/conda-is-corrupted-after-pip-install-conda). But my anaconda was actually working on windows.
I can not reinstall or cover the new anaconda into the old folder where the corrupted old anaconda still be. The alert was saying"you need to find an empty folder".

Don't want to uninstall the old one because of the envs.

Comment: Why don't you install it into another folder then

Comment: yes, I tried, But nothing changed. The old anaconda prompt still have the problem. And for the new one, after the input of "conda info --envs", the old anaconda envs are listed. But still cannot activate the old anaconda envs in it, the warning says “could not find”.

Comment: Because I think the main point is overwrite the old version. If install it in another folder, I just have two anaconda then.

Comment: Okay so you mean you want to install the same version of conda, because the old conda is corrupted

Comment: Yep，I want to install the same version of conda without loss of the old envs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install another python version in your `venv`, you could use

```bash
conda install python=%PYTHON_VERSION%
```

(Replace `%PYTHON_VERSION%` with required python version.)

Comment: The conda which was installed by pip  was not working